# How can return a pointer pointing to the largest value in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is my attempt

```
// Return a pointer to node with the largest value.
// You may assume list has at least one element

Node * pointerToMax(LinkedList *list) {

  assert(list!=NULL);
  assert(list->head != NULL);

  Node *p, *q;
  p = list->head;
  q = list->head;
  int max = q->data;

  while(p != NULL){
    if(p->data > max){
      max = p->data;
    }
    return p;
    p = p->next;
  }
}
```

Here are the struct definitions.

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *next;
};

struct LinkedList {
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
};
```

I'm trying to figure out how to return a pointer that points to the largest value, but I can't exactly figure out how to return the pointer to variable `max`, and I'm not even sure if the `max` variable is being updated correctly.

Comment: You need to keep track of both `max` (the max data) and its corresponding `Node`. Then return a pointer to the `Node`. As it is, you're returning immediately and not giving your `while` loop a chance to iterate through the LL.

Comment: And there is no use of pointer `q` and the return statement should be after the while loop, keeping in mind @bejado 's suggestion

Comment: Your current code is simply going to return the first time you see a node with data greater than the head node. Remove the `return p` statement in the `while` loop and put it after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

You want something like this:

```
Node *maxNode = p;
int max = p->data;
while(p != NULL){
  if(p->data > max){
    max = p->data;
    maxNode = p;
  }
  p = p->next;
}
return maxNode;
```

There is no reason to `return` in your while loop. We don't know what the max `Node` is until we've looped through **all** the nodes.